# Xml deserialize array to list

Tags: c#, .net

I have following xml

```
<result>
    <key accessMask="4294967295" type="Account" expires="">
        <rowset name="characters" key="characterID" columns="characterID,characterName,corporationID,corporationName,allianceID,allianceName,factionID,factionName">
            <row characterID="123" characterName="Sefa 123" corporationID="456" corporationName="Signal Cartel" allianceID="159" allianceName="Scouts" factionID="0" factionName=""/>
            <row characterID="1234" characterName="Sefa 1234" corporationID="987" corporationName="Havos" allianceID="753" allianceName="Unlimited" factionID="0" factionName=""/>
        </rowset>
     </key>
</result>
```

And i have following Schema setup for deserializing this output.

```
    [XmlRoot("result")]
    public class ApiKeyInfo
    {
        [XmlElement("key")]
        public Key Key { get; set; }
    }

    public class Key
    {
        [XmlAttribute("accessMask")]
        public long AccessMask { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("rowset")]
        public List<AccountCharacter> Characters { get; set; }
    }

    public class AccountCharacter
    {
        [XmlAttribute("characterId")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("characterName")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("corporationID")]
        public long CorpId { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("corporationName")]
        public string CorpName { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("allianceID")]
        public long AllianceId { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("allianceName")]
        public string AllianceName { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("factionID")]
        public long FactionId { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("factionName")]
        public string FactionName { get; set; }
    }
```

Problem is, i can't deserialize character informations. Characters list is always containing 0 elements inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
[XmlElement("rowset")]
public List<AccountCharacter> Characters { get; set; }
```

Implies that you'll have a bunch of `rowset` elements, e.g:

```
<rowset characterID="123" characterName="Sefa 123" ...
```

Try this instead:

```
[XmlArray("rowset")]
[XmlArrayItem("row")]
public List<AccountCharacter> Characters { get; set; }
```

A useful tip for these sort of deserialisation problems is to try the process in reverse: create an object and serialise it and see what the XML looks like. It will likely give you some indication as to where your problem is.

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lyC09r) for a working demo, it prints both row name values to the console.

Comment: I mark this as solution because xml output is same as my input when i decorated my class as you show. But i still get 0 objects in my Characters list. I'm still not able to deserialize them into my list it seems.

Comment: @deusExCore you can see in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lyC09r) that it works fine. Not sure what you're doing differently!

Comment: Looks pretty much the same :) I'm using Restsharp to send request and deserialize the response for me. Maybe it's a problem with the Restsharp. Thanks for the answer and fiddle.